# Firebase.auth.currentUser not available on load of page but available after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My problem is that on load of my page, I need to access the information firebase.auth.currentUser, but this information is undefined if I call my function in the eventListener('load). But if I call it on click on a button, here the "add" button, (so a few seconds after page loaded), then it is working.
Here is what I tried in my code.

```
var FIREBASE_AUTH;
var FIREBASE_DATABASE;

const addButton = document.getElementById("add"); 

addButton.addEventListener("click", getEtablissemennts); 

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  FIREBASE_AUTH = firebase.auth();
  FIREBASE_DATABASE = firebase.database();
  getEtablissemennts();
});

function getEtablissemennts(){
  //works only if function is call on click on the button, doesn't work on load of the page
  FIREBASE_DATABASE.ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser.email).once("value", function(snapshot) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect Firebase to authenticate the user and get their data on load. You should set up a listener:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is available now
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user